# Using a variable inside a Chef recipe

Tags: variables, chef-infra, recipe

I'm using chef-cookbook-hostname cookbook to setup node's hostname.  I don't want my hostname to be hard coded in the attribute file (default['set_fqdn']).

Instead the hostname will be read from a VM definition XML file.  I come up with the following default recipe but apparently the variable fqdn is not given value.  Is there any idea why this happens or any better to achieve my task?

```
ruby_block "Find-VM-Hostname" do
   block do
     require 'rexml/document'
     require 'net/http'
     url = 'http://chef-workstation/services.xml'
     file = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
     doc = REXML::Document.new(file)
     REXML::XPath.each(doc, "service_parameters/parameter") do |element|
     if element.attributes["name"].include?"Hostname"
        fqdn = element.attributes["value"]  #this statement does not give value to fqdn
     end
     end
    end
    action :nothing
end
if fqdn
  fqdn = fqdn.sub('*', node.name)
  fqdn =~ /^([^.]+)/
  hostname = Regexp.last_match[1]

  case node['platform']
   when 'freebsd'
    directory '/etc/rc.conf.d' do
      mode '0755'
    end

    file '/etc/rc.conf.d/hostname' do
      content "hostname=#{fqdn}\n"
      mode '0644'
      notifies :reload, 'ohai[reload]'
     end
   else
    file '/etc/hostname' do
       content "#{hostname}\n"
       mode '0644'
       notifies :reload, 'ohai[reload]', :immediately
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 14):

The source of the problem here is that you are setting the variable fqdn inside the scope of a ruby_block and are attempting to make reference to that variable at the compilation phase. The ruby_block resources allows the ability to run ruby code during the convergence phase.

Given that you appear to be using the fqdn to setup the resource set, it looks as though you can remove the ruby block from around the ruby code. e.g.

```
fqdn = // logic to get fqdn

file '/tmp/file' do
  content "fqdn=#{fqdn}"
end
```

Answer (score 11):

I found this in the Chef docs. I ran into a similar issue. I am going to try the `node.run_state`. This information is found at the bottom of this page https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html

> Use `node.run_state` to stash transient data during a chef-client run. This data may be passed between resources, and then evaluated during the execution phase. `run_state` is an empty Hash that is always discarded at the end of the chef-client run.
>
> For example, the following recipe will install the Apache web server, randomly choose PHP or Perl as the scripting language, and then install that scripting language:
>
> ```rb
> package "httpd" do
>   action :install
> end
>
> ruby_block "randomly_choose_language" do
>   block do
>     if Random.rand > 0.5
>       node.run_state['scripting_language'] = 'php'
>     else
>       node.run_state['scripting_language'] = 'perl'
>     end
>   end
> end
>
> package "scripting_language" do
>   package_name lazy { node.run_state['scripting_language'] }
>   action :install
> end
> ```

Comment: I've tried something similar (assign a variable in the run_state and retrieve it in a template) and the node.run_state command always returned an empty value in the package call so this doesn't work universally as it seems.

Comment: Had the run_state, forgot the lazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this link 
http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2015-03/msg00266.html
you can use node.run_state[:variables] for parsing one variable to another recipe

Here is my code ::
**file.rb**

node.run_state[:script_1] = "foo"
include_recipe  'provision::copy'

and in other copy.rb file put following code ::

**copy.rb**

filename = node.run_state[:script_1]
puts "Name is #{filename}"

Answer (score 1):

I used `node.run_state['variable']` for the same purpose and was successfully able to do it. Please find basic sample code below.

```
ruby_block "resource_name" do
   block do
     node.run_state['port_value'] = 1432
   end
end

ruby_block "resource_name2" do
   block do
      num = node.run_state['variable']
   end
end
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: To get value of run_state in the recipe other than for value assignment, use  `#{node.run_state['variable']}`