# how to add same cookbook recipe in other and how to access variables from included recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

How to add same cook book recipe in other recipe

```
  include_recipe  "localcookbook::test"
```

where i have included there test recipe variables are not passing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a variable inside a Chef recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551104/using-a-variable-inside-a-chef-recipe)

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are not visible across an include because that would make them not local variables. Or more generally because that isn't how Ruby works.

Comment: Means need to declare global variable, Ok help me .Know I am asking general questions i am beginner as Devops

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want you need to use cookbook's helpers and libraries. As a start you can check this resources for libraries https://blog.chef.io/2014/03/12/writing-libraries-in-chef-cookbooks/

This is basic examples with helpers.

In your cookbook folder you needs to create libraries/helpers.rb file

```
module MyCookbook
  module Helpers
    @@state_value ||= ''

    def set_state_value(v)
      @@state_value = v
      @@state_value
    end

    def get_state_value
      @@state_value
    end
  end
end

Chef::Recipe.send(:include, MyCookbook::Helpers)
```

Lets say that you have two recipes - A and B (executed sequently) in chef.

In A you put `set_state_value("state value")` and in B `get_state_value` and you have what you set from A recipe in B recipe.