# How to pass variables in Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I'm wondering how I can manage this with Chef and variables.
I have my default section with the following variable

```
node.default['common']['docker'] = "18.09.1"
```

So, I want to manage the version via the variable

```
 remote_file 'docker'-node['common']['docker'] do
    source 'https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-'node['common']['docker']'.tgz'
        owner 'root'
        group 'root'
        mode '0755'
        action :create
    end

bash 'install docker' do
    code <<-EOH
            tar xzvf node['common']['docker']
            sudo cp docker/* /usr/bin/
            sudo groupadd docker
            sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
            sudo dockerd &
            EOH
end
```

But i'm getting this error

```
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
FATAL: SyntaxError: /tmp/packer-chef-solo/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/recipes/common.rb:90: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: found a similar thread in addition to below answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551104/using-a-variable-inside-a-chef-recipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [string/variable interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html). Chef attributes are same as variables in programming languages like Ruby.

String interpolation in Ruby is performed by using `"#{}"` syntax. Any variable/attribute within the curly braces will be interpolated.

So your `remote_file` resource should look like this:

```rb
remote_file "/tmp/docker-#{node['common']['docker']}.tgz" do
  source "https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-#{node['common']['docker']}.tgz"
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end
```

Note that I have used outer double quotes `"` as it is required for interpolation. Also I have included the destination path as `/tmp` to save the file.

Comment: If I wanto to put it on a bash code with EOH: tar xzvf "/tmp/docker-#{node['common']['docker']}.tgz" will be like this?

Comment: That's correct. You may also want to set the `cwd` or `-C path/to/extract` for the `tar` command, like: `tar xzf "/tmp/docker-#{node['common']['docker']}.tgz" -C /tmp`. That said, have a look at [archive_file resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/archive_file/)  to do this extraction idempotently.